# I can't generate a word cloud with some images

Tags: python-3.x, word-cloud

I just start the module worcloud in Python 3.7, and I'm using the next cxode to generate wordclouds from a dictionary and I'm trying to use differents masks, but this works for some images: in two cases works with images of 831x816 and 1000x808. This has to be with the size of the image?  Or is because the images is kind a blurry? Or what is it?

I paste my code:

```
from PIL import Image

our_mask = np.array(Image.open('twitter.png'))

twitter_cloud = WordCloud(background_color = 'white', mask = our_mask)
twitter_cloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)

twitter_cloud.to_file("twitter_cloud.jpg")

plt.imshow(twitter_cloud)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a black-and-white image I used. What fixed it for me was when I cropped the image more closely to the black drawing so there was no unnecessary bulk white area on the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Some images should be adjusted for the process. Note only white point values for image is mask_out (other values are mask_in). The problem is that some of images are not suitable for masking. The reason is  that the color's np.array somewhat mismatches. To solve this, following can be done:
1.Creating mask object: (Please try with your own image as I couldn't upload:)

```
import numpy as np;
import pandas as pd;
from PIL import Image;
from wordcloud import WordCloud

mask = np.array(Image.open("filepath/picture.png"))
print(mask)
```

If the output values for white np.array is 255, then it is okay. But if it is 0 or probably other value, we have to change this to 255.

2.In the case of other values, the code for changing the values:
2-1. Create function for transforming (here our value = 0)

```
def transform_zeros(val):
    if val == 0: 
       return 255
    else:
       return val
```

2-2. Creating the same shaped np.array:

```
maskable_image = np.ndarray((mask.shape[0],mask.shape[1]), np.int32)
```

2-3. Transformation:

```
for i in range(len(mask)):
    maskable_image[i] = list(map(transform_zeros, mask[i]))
```

3.Checking:

```
print(maskable_image)
```

Then you can use this array for your mask.

```
mask = maskable_image
```

All this is copied and interpreted from this [link](https://www.holisticseo.digital/python-seo/word-cloud/), so check it if you find my attempted explanation unclear, as I just provided solution but don't understand that much about color arrays of image and its transformation.

Comment: I think the transformation can be simplified with `mask[mask == 0] = 255 `.